# render Custom Field Type

Tags: xslt, custom-field-types

I have a Custom Filed Type which is rendered in default view (using a simple XSL) like this

StreetName,1,K1,2,1,3,Los Angeles,90210

It's an simple adress.
How can I render it like

StreetName, nr. 1

Building K1, Floor 2, Entrance 1, Apt. 3

Los Angeles, 90210

Thank's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you change the delimiter of the field type to something like a semi-colon?  It would make it easier to isolate when the breaking should occur.  You could then use a XSL Template like [this](http://spxslt.codeplex.com/discussions/259103):

```
<xsl:template name="StringSplit">
  <xsl:param name="val" />
   <xsl:choose>  
    <xsl:when test="contains($val, ';')">   
     <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($val, ';')" />
     <br />     
      <xsl:call-template name="StringSplit">     
       <xsl:with-param name="val" select="substring-after($val, ';')" />     
      </xsl:call-template>  
   </xsl:when>  
   <xsl:otherwise>      
    <xsl:value-of select="$val" />
   </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: The field is a Custom Field Type and yhe delimiter is added by default I think by SharePoint.
I've tried a lot of things like param and variables but it seems it can't be incremented using XSLT.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not quite sure how to handle that then, maybe others will chime in with some input.